# Converting string in char array in CPP

Tags: c++, arrays, i2c

I am working on a project and I am stuck at this for a while.
I have to pass to the "write" function a char array.I tried to convert the "data" curenty string to char arrays using `https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-std-string-char-cpp/`  but i get only errors

```
error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘data’, which is of pointer type ‘const string*’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*’} (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
     char* c[] = const_cast<char*>(data.c_str());
```

```
void LCD::print(const std::string* data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++)
        write(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: `std::string::c_str()` is a thing. It returns a null-terminated `char*`.
`std::string::data()` returns a non-null-terminated `char*`

Comment: The variable `data` is a *pointer* to a string object. If it's a single string object then you should pass it by *reference* instead of using pointers. As in `const std::string& data`. Otherwise you need to dereference the pointer before you can use the string object (as in `(*data)[i]`, or `data->length()`).

Comment: Also `strlen` is a C null-terminated character array function, it will not work with a `std::string` (pointer or object).

Comment: All in all it seems you might need to take a step or two back, and refresh some of the basics of C++.

Comment: @AndreasDM On the other hand, since C++11 all strings wrapped by `std::string` are required to be null-terminated, which implies that `data()` must return a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const std::string*
> ```

It's hardly ever a good idea to pass a `std::string` pointer into a function. I recommend not doing such thing. How to replace it depends on your intentions. Reference to const is a typical default choice if you're passing a single string.

> ```
> strlen(data)
> ```

The `strlen` function does not accept an argument of type `const std::string*`. This program is ill-formed.

If you want the length of a `std::string`, you can use the `size` member function.

> ```
> write(data[i]);
> ```

Here, you're using subscript operator to access the `i`th `std::string` object within an array of `std::string` objects pointed by `data`.

The `strlen` usage and the description imply that there is only one string involved which contradicts this array iteration.

---

> ```
> error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘data’, which is of pointer type ‘const string*’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*’}
> (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
>      char* c[] = const_cast<char*>(data.c_str());
> ```

The error message explains what you did wrong. `data` is a pointer. Pointers don't have member functions. You tried to call the member function `c_str` of the pointer which doesn't exist.

The error message also suggests the likely solution. If you indirect through the pointer (using the indirecting member access operator `->`) to access the pointed string, then you will access the `c_str` member function of the string. `std::string` does have such member function.

There's another bug in the quoted code. You're trying to use the returned pointer to initialise an array of pointers `c`. That's not possible. There's only one pointer returned, and it doesn't make much sense to create an array of one elements in this case.

---

> I have to pass to the "write" function a char array

I suspect that you actually mean, you have to pass a pointer to first element of a null terminated char array. It can be done like this:

```
std::string data = ...;
write(data.c_str());
```

It's so trivial, that I wouldn't recommend writing a function for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that `strlen` accepts a `const char*` while you're supplying a `const string*`. You can **solve** this by using the `size()` member function of `std::string` as follows:

```
void print(const std::string* data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (*data).size(); i++)//first we dereference the pointer named data then call the size() member function on pointed string object
        write((*data)[i]); //first we dereference the pointer named data then access the ith element of the pointed string object 
}
```

Comment: `(*data).size()` can alternatively be (and should be) written as `data->size()`. But, since C++11, a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) would make more sense: `for (char ch : *data) write(ch);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau The notation `data->` and `(*data).` are equivalent. It is not my responsibility to write every equivalent form of every expression. **Second** which loop to use is OP's choice. I corrected only what was syntactically and logically wrong with OP's code snippet so that he no longer get the compiler error that he was originally getting.